# Displaying Each entry using PDO Statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get few entries of a Table using this code

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM players WHERE longitude > :long1 AND longitude < :long2 AND latitude > :lat1 AND latitude < :lat2 AND id != :mPlayerId ');
            $statement->bindParam(':long1', $long1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':long2', $long2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':lat1' , $lat1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':lat2' , $lat2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindParam(':myPlayerId' , $myPlayerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->execute();

            if(!($players = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
            {
                return false;
            }

            $conn = null;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
```

Now I want to get each entry . Suppose each entry contains id, name, email.
How can i get each entries data?

I have this code in my mind, can someone check if that's what i need or need something else?

```
foreach($players as $player)
        {
        this->ShowResult($player->id,$player->email);
        }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you need in _your_ project? BTW, you need `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` won't produce an object, if that's what you mean. Were you thinking of `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario $players contains all the entries e.g it has 10 entries data. Now i want to access each entry and get its id and email and whatever the database is.

Comment: @PLB Pleas read the question again, i explicitly said that How can i get each entries data? since $players contain all the entries

Comment: How about enabling `error_reporting` when something doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```
foreach($players as $player)
{
    this->ShowResult($player['id'],$player['email']);
}
```

Should do the thrick